# How to reinfer datatype of a Spark Dataframe column after updating values in the column in Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is a sample of my original dataframe `df`

```
+----+
| mix|
+----+
|   1|
|   2|
| cap|
|   3|
|  53|
|  56|
|  98|
|  90|
+----+
```

The current datatype of the column is `StringType`
After replacing the value `cap` with `0` , there could be two cases

- Column did not have any more string values , so all values are numeric now
- Column had other string values so it will remain `StringType`

How to infer datatype again so i can know if the column is purely numerical after replacement or not.And if `Numerical` , what is the exact datatype viz `Integer`, `Float` ,`Double`

```
df.withColumn("mix",when(col("mix") === "cap",0).otherwise(col("mix")))
```

Comment: Use rlike to determine if each column contains only digits or not.

Comment: @Nick Is this function avaiable in scala spark

Comment: Yes, it's defined on Column.

Comment: `rlike` will tell me if all values are numerical or not but it wont tell me the exact datatype of the updated column like `Integer`, `Float` `Double`
Updated the question accordingly

Comment: Why can't you do it with rlike? You can detect decimal points. Don't bother with floats, just use double.

Answer (score 1):

```
val mix = Seq("1","2","cap","4").toDF("mix")    
mix.printSchema()
root
|-- mix: string (nullable = true)

val after = mix.withColumn("mix",when(col("mix") === "cap",0).otherwise(col("mix")).cast(IntegerType))
after.printSchema()
root
|-- mix: integer (nullable = true)
```

Let me know, if this helps you.

Comment: Explicit `cast` is not an option since the column could still be `StringType` because of some other string values.Have updated the question accordingly